# What is this entry in my ssh known_hosts file?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, chinese, known-hosts

I was taking a look at my ssh known_hosts file, and it only included 2 entries. The first line was the GitHub keys, so nothing weird there. However, the second line had a bunch of Chinese text, which I have no idea where it came from.

I instinctively deleted the line so I cannot share it here, but I did copy/paste it into Google Translate before doing so. There didn't seem to be any IP addresses or any numbers at all. It also didn't seem to be full sentences, but that may have been due to Google Translate.

It's also worth noting that the only two reasons I used ssh before the "last modified" date of the file was to use GitHub and to ssh into my university in the U.S.

What could that have been? Where could it have come from? Is that normal to have in your known_hosts file?

Comment: Same issue seen here. Any solution or reason why found?